# How to send a fixeddocument to a network printer using WCF (C#)?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf, printing

I have a client application in WPF that is using WCF services. I am completely new to WCF services.

In the WPF client I have a fixed document that I wish to print to a specific network printer. The printer is a stand-alone printer connected directly to the network.

How do I send a document to a printer using WCF services? (or is there a better way?)

(The WCF is located on the client machine. This is not a web page and nothing I've read addresses this simple question).

Thank you for any help or direction (I'm at a loss where to start).

Comment: Windows (and the printer driver) will abstract all of that complexity for you (thank goodness!).

Comment: @Jeff Does WCF communicate with printers?

Comment: As you enumerate the printers added to the current system, the network printers have a network printer driver.  That network printer driver will handle all of the details.  If the printer is not in the list, and you wish to communicate with it directly, and then WCF will not likely be the best fit.

Answer (score 1):

The way to achieve really depends on the way you can interface with the printer.

1. Find documentation for the printer and see if that allows you to print to it directly. For e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Open_Extensibility_Platform_(OXP)#Device_Service_APIs
2. Install the correct printer drivers on the client machines and select that driver. That's the approach that we use in our applications.

Comment: So...Windows Communication Foundation..does not communicate with printers?

Comment: Not exactly WCF is a technology that allows the developer to create services within their own application. However it has nothing to do with consuming services from third parties.  It's however quickly being replaced with web api as the more common service implementation on the .net platform at least in the projects that i have been working on. However on big advantage of WCF and older style webservices is that they could use WDSL to generate client side code.